# Vimeo API upload TUS being ignored

Tags: vimeo-api

I am uploading via the API, passing upload.approach as tus, but it seems to be ignoring my json body (as the response is not correct for TUS).

`POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer token
```

```
{
    "upload": {
        "approach": "tus",
        "size": 18353311
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "uri": "/users/syngency/uploads/...",
  "ticket_id": "...",
  "user": {
      ...
  },
  "upload_link": "https://...",
  "form": "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"https://"> ... </form>",
  "upload_link_secure": "https://....cloud.vimeo.com/upload?tick
```

No upload object as expected/documented.

Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong, or is this something broken on Vimeo's side?

EDIT: Permissions on Personal Access Tokens are:

```
private create edit delete upload video_files public
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, you have specify all the headers, including Accept:

```
"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4"
```